# Product of Array Except Self - Leet Code Time Limit Exceeded

Tags: java, performance, optimization

I have been solving problem(Product of Array Except Self) on leetcode.
My code compile successfully and passed 18 out of 19 test cases. I try to figure out the failed test case but no luck.

Exception: Time Limit Exceeded

Input: https://leetcode.com/submissions/detail/439297112/testcase/ - (70000 integers)

My Code

```
public int[] productExceptSelf(int[] nums) {
       int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
       return mySolution(arr);
   }
   
   public static int[] mySolution(int arr[]) {
       int size = arr.length;
       int j;
       int product;
       int[] result = new int[size];
       for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
           j = 0;
           product = 1;
           while (j < size) {
               if (j == i) {
                   j++;
                   continue;
               }
               product *= arr[j];
               j++;
           }

           result [i] = product;
       }

       return result;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this logic should reduce your time. I haven't checked it.

```
product = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    product *= arr[j];
}
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    result[i] = product/arr[i]
}
```

Comment: Output will be wrong, I do have alternatives for this problem but I want to find mentioned issue in existing code.

Comment: Can you give the full description of the problem?. I thought you have print an array which has the product of all the elements in an array skipping the value of the respective index.

Comment: You should avoid using 2 loops to reduce time complexity.

Comment: Here is the problem https://leetcode.com/problems/product-of-array-except-self/

Comment: This solution would work if the input array contains a zero. example `[1,2,3,4,0,6]`